# SBT published jar corrupt

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy

I am having a really strange problem:

I have a multi-module sbt project containing libraries that I publish locally.
Every once in a while the published jar is really a POM file!

Meaning I can open it with a text editor and see the POM for the library in question instead of the class files.

cleaning and rebuilding/republishing sometimes fixes it temporarily.
Also note that the jar in 'target/scala-2.11' is also a POM file.

Here is the Build.scala and sbt file for the libraries. (names are changed to protect the guilty :) due to company policies)

```
    //////////////////Build.scala

    import java.io._
    import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files}

    import sbt._
    import xerial.sbt.Pack._

    object Library extends Build {
      lazy val rootProj = Project(id = "library", base = file(".")) aggregate(
        projA,
        projB,
        projC,
        projD
      )

      lazy val projA = Project(id = "projectA", base = file("ProjectA"))

      lazy val projB = Project(id = "projectB", base = file("ProjectB"))

      lazy val projC = Project(id = "projectC", base = file("ProjectC"))
        .dependsOn(spatialMathProj)


      lazy val projD = Project(id = "projectD", base = file("ProjectD"))
    }


    //////////////////build.sbt for projectD

    name := "ProjectD"

    version := "2.0-SNAPSHOT"

    scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

    publishArtifact in (Compile, packageDoc) := false

    publishArtifact in (Compile, packageSrc) := false

    libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.2"

    libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-remote" % "2.4.2"

    libraryDependencies += "net.sf.jung" % "jung2" % "2.0.1"

    libraryDependencies += "net.sf.jung" % "jung-graph-impl" % "2.0.1"

    libraryDependencies += "net.sf.jung" % "jung-visualization" % "2.0.1"

    libraryDependencies += "com.plexsys" % "api_2.11" % "2.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

Has anyone else seen this?
Why is this happening?

I am using sbt version 0.13.7.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: which command do you use to publish? is the code private or is a public repo? have you tried to do a `sbt publishLocal` to see if it happens?

Comment: Just curious, why do you have lines `publishArtifact in (Compile, packageDoc) := false` and `publishArtifact in (Compile, packageSrc) := false`? Once I had an issue with single quotes around project name. Triple quotes solved it, strange...

Comment: It is a private repo. I used publish-local.

Comment: The 'publishArtifact' line is not necessary. It was an attempt to resolve another strange issue we had that turned out to be due to renaming an artifact.

Comment: Update: It turns out that there was another library with the same name in a different project. That library was empty. Since it was published last it overwrote the previous one. The only remaining mystery is why the jar was really a pom file.